# System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\approot\

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I have an xml file in my project at the root directory that is supposed to be used for read/write operations. And this code works fine when i run it on my local machine, however it throws

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'E:\approot\...
```

when the application is deployed on Cloud. I have also tried adding following setting for elevated permissions in csdef file

```
<Runtime executionContext="elevated"></Runtime>
```

still no luck. Is Read/Write permission at root directory is not given in Azure? Here I am trying to write from the same application to its root folder. I am using following code to get the file path

```
string baseDirectoryParent = Directory.GetParent(baseDirectory).Parent.FullName;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you should use localstorage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758708.aspx

Comment: @ThiagoCutodio This will not help much as the xml file is the sitemap for my website and it must be kept at the root folder. Local storage will create a sub directory in the root folder.(Correct me if I am wrong I am new to Azure)

Comment: You are right, I thought it was for parametrization or something related. If you include the .xml in your project and publish it, you'll be able to open the xml as http://yourdomain.cloudapp.net/yourfile.xml

Comment: I am able to read these file but unable to update them programatically. Also I have included these files in the project.

Comment: Well, there's no easy way to update programatically: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19423110/1384539

Comment: @gjdev.tech do you need any other help?